# First 'property' of node-postgres error object

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, node-postgres

Anybody know what the first pseudo-property is in my error object on a faulty query?  When I `console.log('' + error);` it grabs the text within the brackets to display.  Other than that, I'm not sure how to reference that property.

```
{ [error: function XXXXXXXXXX does not exist]
   name: 'error',
   length: 226,
   severity: 'ERROR',
   code: '42883',
   detail: undefined,
   hint: 'No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.',
   position: '8',
   internalPosition: undefined,
   internalQuery: undefined,
   where: undefined,
   file: 'parse_func.c',
   line: '306',
   routine: 'ParseFuncOrColumn' }
```

Answer (score 0):

Property `message` will give you access to the error message itself.